# Hyperledger design for multiple asset types

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am working on a Hyperledger prototype for multiple currency savings account scenario for students. In basic terms, I need to support multiple users from different schools, with each user able to store in an e-wallet in multiple currencies. At first, we will support just USD and CNY.

What would be a good hyperledger fabric design (better scalability, maintainability in case new currencies are supported in future)?

1. Use JSON string as value in data store, use CouchDB for better rich queries on chaincode data. E.g. Key=user,value={"usd":100, "cny":100}
2. Each currency handling is itself a new channel, own set of chaincode.

Please help guys, I am new to Hyperledger and it will be very useful if you can explain clearly your response too.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way to model this is to use composite keys. Ie (in your notation):

Key={user, "USD"},Value=100

Check out [marbles02 example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/ca8fad315128a528dc8f3eab2395105723d5f95b/chaincode/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go#L208) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement currency on top of Hyperledger Fabric you need to implement your own [VSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/vscc/validator_onevalidsignature.go) (validation system chaincode) because you need to prevent double spending.

Then you need to plug it into this [file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/importsysccs.go).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a list of features / use cases you'd like to be able to support? For example, do you expect / need

- the ability to exchange currencies in and across accounts
- a high volume of transfers across accounts
- is this just a fairly simple wallet with low volume of transactions?

I'd start with a basic design which includes an account, a single currency and the ability to perform simple operations such as load and transfer (if you expect to transfer money across accounts?)